# A question related to Helly's Theorem on convex sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, convex-analysis, combinatorial-geometry

I have one  question  related to differential geometry. Initilally, I am giving some background and my question is after that.

**Helly's Theorem** 
Let C be a finite family of convex sets in $R^n$ such that, for $k ≤ n + 1$, any $k$ members of C have a nonempty intersection. Then the intersection of all members of C is nonempty.

As an application of Helly's therore we have:

**Corollary** : Given $s (s > 0)$ points in the plane such that every three of them are contained in a disk of radius $1$. Prove that all $s$ points are contained in a disk of radius $1$.

**Proof** Consider the set C of unit disks with centers at the points from a given set. Since every three of the given points are contained in a unit disk, any three disks from C have a nonempty intersection. By Helly's Theorem, all the disks have a nonempty intersection. Let $q$ be a point from the intersection. Then $q$ belongs to every disk from C and is, therefore, at a distance less than $1$ from there centers. In other words, all the centers of the disks from C lie in a disk of radius $1$ centered at $q$.

**Now like previous corollary does the follwoing  also true ?**

Given $s (s > 0)$ points in the plane such that every $6$ or $7$ of them are contained in two disk of radius $1$. Then all $s$ points are contained in two disk of radius $1$.

Comment: Also posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/111442/a-question-related-to-hellys-theorem-on-convex-sets --- with no reference on either site to the other site. Gross breach of etiquette.